# Sending extra, non-model data in a save request with backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, rest, backbone.js

I'm looking for a solution for dealing with an issue of state between models using backbone.js.

I have a time tracking app where a user can start/stops jobs and it will record the time the job was worked on. I have a job model which holds the job's data and whether it is currently 'on'.

Only 1 job can be worked on at a time. So if a user starts a job the currently running job must be stopped. I'm wondering what the best solution to do this is. I mean I could simply toggle each job's 'on' parameter accordingly and then call save on each but that results in 2 requests to the server each with a complete representation of each job.

Ideally it would be great if I could piggyback additional data in the save request similarly to how it's possible to send extra data in a fetch request. I only need to send the id of the currently running job and since this really is unrelated to the model it needs to be sent *alongside* the model, not part of it.

Is there a good way to do this? I guess I could find a way to maintain a reference to the current job server side if need be :\

Answer (score 8, accepted):

when you call a save function, the first parameter is an object of the data that's going to be saved.  Instead of just calling `model.save()`, create an object that has the model data and your extra stuff.

inside of your method that fires off the save:

```
...
var data = this.model.toJSON();
data.extras = { myParam : someData };

this.model.save(data, {success: function( model, response ) {
    console.log('hooray it saved: ', model, response);
});
...
```

Comment: Its important to note that while this does send the additional non-model data, it will then _set_ the data on the model and then become model data. Like in my case, you may not want this and just want to send 1 or 2 extra params in the request not meant for the model. You need to `this.model.unset('foo', { silent: true })` to then remove the additional properties

Comment: @ryanmarc however this does the work for sending the additional data but  this is not a good method for sending the data with model .

Comment: @RobinsGupta Instead of commenting that an answer over 2 years old isn't correct, why not add an updated answer that is?  Backbone was in a much different state in 2012 than it is today.